# Flexbox: how do you prevent non-overlapping buttons from resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, calendar, overlap

I am trying to make a calendar app where I add events (buttons) to the calendar (table). However, I am struggling with event collisions.

My data structure for the calendar is as follows: It is a table with two rows (one header, one body). The first row's columns have the day ID. The second row has the events for that day.

**The Problem**: If I add multiple events into the second row's cell and there is a collision then the events overlap. I tried to get around this with flexbox. This works with two overlapping tags, but now the non-overlapping tags are also resizing!!! And if there is no event collision, I want the tag to be at maximum width.

**I am putting a visual of the problem here:** [See Photo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmZvO.png)

I am placing the **Full(-ish) Code Here** in case I am not giving the full information below: https://codepen.io/samuel-solomon/pen/oNbKeRm

Here is my collision problem:

```
<td class="day_Block">
   <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="M">
      <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_2" style="height: 12rem; top: 0rem; background-color: rgb(83, 94, 235);">M8:00 - 12:00<br>CS 2<br></button>
      <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(254, 44, 84);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
      <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(19, 202, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
   </div>
</td>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.day_Block {
  position: relative;
}

.flexbox_Edits {
  top:0;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 42rem;
}

.event_Button {
  border-width: 2px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: inset solid solid;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.event_Button_Text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 550;
  letter-spacing: 0.06rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new contributor as well so I can't comment to ask a few more questions about the problem, hope this will help: On the css class "event_Button" you have a max-width: 100% and width: 100%. As width:100% is last on the style, then max-width is not "used" by css. Also, I tried removing the float: left because there is already a left: 0.

```
.event_Button {
  border-width: 2px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: inset solid solid;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;   
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 }
```

It seemed to work for me but if it's not the solution I'll try again.

Comment: I did try that however that doesnt help. In fact, then none of the tags reach the end. Thank you for trying though! I really appreciate it (let me know if there is another way). If it worked for you, can I see a full code snippet?

Comment: I added a full codepen in case my snippet above was not enough. Sorry

Comment: Hey, sorry to hear it didn't work. I guess I misunderstood the problem and that's why I thought it worked for me hahaha. I thought the problem was with the max-width and the width thing. Hope you get it right. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the all the buttons have identical classes and are sharing a single flex-container. When there are more than one buttons in a single line, they need to be identified differently so as to apply some unique styles on them.

In this example, the flex-container is set to `wrap` and the buttons are given `flex: 1 0 100%` property by default. When there are two buttons in a single line, they are given `.two-events` class, which contains the `flex: 1 0 50%` property. Similarly `.three-events` class contains `flex:1 0 33.33%` property and so on.

```css
.day_Block {
  position: relative;
}

.flexbox_Edits {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.event_Button {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: inset solid solid;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.event_Button_Text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 550;
  letter-spacing: 0.06rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
}

.two-events {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.three-events {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<td class="day_Block">
  <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="M">
    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_2" style="height: 12rem; top: 0rem; background-color: rgb(83, 94, 235);">M8:00 - 12:00<br>CS 2<br></button>

    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1 two-events" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(254, 44, 84);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1 two-events" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(19, 202, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>

    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1 three-events" style="height: 21rem; top: 36rem; background-color: rgb(254, 34, 84);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1 three-events" style="height: 21rem; top: 36rem; background-color: rgb(19, 102, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
    <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1 three-events" style="height: 21rem; top: 36rem; background-color: rgb(19, 02, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Instead of giving a different `class`, you can also dynamically inline the `flex` property. Similar to `height`,`top` and  `background-color`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem, except introduced a new one. Now the absolute positioning from the parent div flexbox is all messed up. The styling command top: 18rem is now from the blue event not the top of the column. Is there a way to prevent this while still implementing your solution?

Comment: Also I am dynamically adding/removing events into the columns. Is there one class I can give to allow it to automate the flex: 1 0 x%; so that if I add another event into the column the width automatically adjusts (or doesnt if it doesnt collide). Thank you so much for all your help!!!